# Plot pandas dataframe with group category overlaped

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframe which I need to plot and see which category has the highest score. Here is the data frame code, if the plot can be overlapped by category with different color that would great.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
idx = pd.date_range('02-28-2018', '04-29-2018')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[ '101', '2018-03-29', 'Smooth','9.0'], [
         '102', '2018-03-29', 'Hard','1.0',
    ], [ '103', '2018-03-30', 'Narrow','1.1'], [
         '104', '2018-04-30', 'Sharp','2.0'
    ], [ '105', '2018-04-21', 'Narrow','2.2'],[ '105', '2018-05-21', 'Narrow','2.1'],[ '105', '2018-05-22', 'Narrow','2.0']],
    columns=[ 'accountid', 'timestamp', 'category','score'])

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df=df.set_index(['timestamp'])
print(df)



      accountid category score
timestamp                          
2018-03-29       101   Smooth   9.0
2018-03-29       102     Hard   1.0
2018-03-30       103   Narrow   1.1
2018-04-30       104    Sharp   2.0
2018-04-21       105   Narrow   2.2
2018-05-21       105   Narrow   2.1
2018-05-22       105   Narrow   2.0
```

Comment: Do you mean which category has the highest mean score? What kind of plot do you want? Barplot?

Comment: I mean the scores over the month as a line graph for each category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['score'] = df['score'].astype('float')    
df.reset_index().set_index(['timestamp', 'category'])['score'].unstack('category').plot(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Let's say if I have a duplicate score like "[ '101', '2018-03-29', 'Smooth','9.0'],[ '101', '2018-03-29', 'Smooth','9.0'],, this will fail with "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicate row issue, while creating the index append the timestamp and category columns.

```
df['score'] = df['score'].astype('float')    
df.reset_index().set_index(['timestamp', 'category'],append=True) \
['score'].unstack('category').plot(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```